# Restrict a select in a relational query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following relationships

Asset has many size.
Size has one asset.

I get my data out like:

```
$data = Asset::with('size')->where('active', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

How can I restrict the data returned via the above query? The following restricts the asset data:

```
$data = Asset::with('size')->where('active', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get(array('id', 'name');
```

But I need to restrict the data coming from size.

I've tried the following in the size model, but no luck:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Asset')->select(array('asset_id', 'name'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a condition for the eager load:

```
$data = Asset::with(array('size'=> function($query)
{
    $query->select('id','name','asset_id'); // asset_id is needed for mapping
}))->where('active', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Additionally, you'd be able to set a `hidden` variable in your model if you need it to automatically restrict certain things that you don't want the user to see.  `protected $hidden = array('password');`